# Deleting a document on Firebase Firestore using its autoID

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I made an automobile management application.

After the user registers with his e-mail address and logs in, he adds a vehicle and enters other information under it.

The license plates of these vehicles are displayed in a recycler view.

Clicking on the plate takes you to a screen that shows the information it has filled in.

I put a delete button on this screen.

However, as I have shown in my code, how can I show the auto-generated ID of the opened page to delete it?

1. Page showing plates [plates page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvYqO.png)
2. The page that contains the clicked plate and the delete button (with a red frame) [info page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sISE9.png)
3. My Firebase Firestore min display [Firebase Firestore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EOaxe.png)

I don't know how to code.

I'm trying to watch video lessons and adapt them the way I want to make the applications in my head.

This application is the last point I came to.

As far as I saw the answers to the previous questions and the videos, I could not answer this question.

I know it will be difficult, but can you show this ignorant the correct method?

```
public void deleteCarsClicked(View view) {
    firebaseFirestore.collection("Arabalar").document("How do I show the ID of the opened page here.")
            .delete()
            .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void unused) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(RstActivity.this, CarsActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(RstActivity.this, e.getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
}
```

Comment: You'll need to know the ID of the document you want to delete. Typically you do this by storing the ID when you load the document from the database to show it in your UI. Then when the user clicks the delete button, you pass that ID to your `deleteCarsClicked` method so that it can pass it to Firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @FrankvanPuffelen mentioned in his comment, to be able to delete a particular document, you need to know its document ID. For example, if you have the following schema:

```
db-root
 |
 --- licensePlates (collection)
      |
      --- $licensePlateId (document)
            |
            --- code: "34FHR147"
            |
            --- licensePlateId: "FirestoreDocumentId"
```

To delete this document, you call delete() as you can see below:

```
FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
db.collection("licensePlates")
  .document("FirestoreDocumentId")
  .delete()
  .addOnCompleteListener(/*.../*);
```

If you however don't know the "FirestoreDocumentId", then you have to perform a query:

```
Query queryByLicensePlate = db.collection("licensePlates").whereEqualTo("code", "34FHR147");
queryByLicensePlate.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                document.getReference().delete().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> deleteTask) {
                        if (deleteTask.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Document successfully deleted.");
                        } else {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Error deleting document: ", deleteTask.getException());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you have solved the problem that I have been struggling with for days with one answer.